# How to set cancel timeout on MongoCursor with Mongo-Java API 3

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to set the QUERYOPTION_NOTIMEOUT flag when doing a find() query.
The flag overrides the default 10 minutes timeout on MongoCursor.

According to the [Documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html)  find() should return a DBCursor:

```
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
```

And then I can do

```
cursor.addOption(Bytes.QUERYOPTION_NOTIMEOUT);
```

But find() actually returns FindIterableImpl /  which doesn't have the addOption() method.

Here's the entire method for context:

```
public static MongoCursor getSomethingFromDB(String something) {
    MongoCollection collection = getCollectionForClass(BlogPost.class);
    return collection.find(and(exists("a", false), eq("other", something))).iterator();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to do this on the version 3 of the mongo-java driver is:

```
collection.find(and(exists("a", false), eq("other", lang))).noCursorTimeout(true).iterator();
```

Apparently the

```
cursor.addOption(Bytes.QUERYOPTION_NOTIMEOUT);
```

is from the V2 API and the V3 documentation is outdated

Comment: I have the same problem, but on the aggregate method. Aggregate returns an AggregateIterable, and this only has a useCursor(Boolean bln) method, but I cannot find a way to actually modify the cursor settings. So I always end up with a CursorNotFoundException.